Intersecting Droplets
I am struggling to get rid of these intersectiong droplets (created using the GEOMETRY NODE), any idea how to fix this overlapping using GEOMETRY NODE so that the intersectiong droplets will fuse together?


Blender file: 
Many thanks

Try changing the Distribute Points on Faces node to Poisson and adjust Distance Min.

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? I think that with two Distribute Points on Faces  nodes ignoring each other, you have to expect overlap...

Changing the Distribute Points on Faces node to Poisson and adjust Distance Min it wont' hel as there are two indipendent Distribute Points on Faces, one is for big drops abd the ther one is for tiny drops.

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
Removing points too close to big droplets from the Instance on Points node for small droplets could prevent overlapping between small and big ones:

NB 1: New nodes are in dark red.
NB 2: Method for scattering points for big droplets is set to Poisson Disk with a Distance Min set slightly larger than the Radius of the UV Sphere modelling big droplets to avoid overlapping.
NB 3: The proposed approach fails if the radius of small droplets is too small compared to the radius of big ones.
1. Faces of big droplets are set as Target of a Geometry Proximity node.
2. The Selection mask of the Instance on Points node for small droplets is rejecting Points that are at a Distance lower than an adjustable threshold, set slightly larger than the Radius of the UV Sphere modelling small droplets.

Of course it would be nice if the Distribute Points on Faces node would accept different distances, but this is a great approach/solution! Well done!

@quellenform: Thank you !

@StefLAncien - I really appreciate the time you have spent to explain the issue in detail. Thanks for your tips!
